# ReportViewer no carga el Reporte

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssrs

Tengo un proyecto en ASP.NET VS2017 con c# framework 4.6.1, en el cual uso reportes SSRS a hacer pruebas localmente me muestra los reportes bien, pero al publicar el sitio me muestra este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aclaro que los datos los ingrese manualmente desde el diseño, no hay tablix, ni formulas

Esta es la info que quiero mostrar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código aspx, no hay codigo behind, aclaro que antes (la semana pasada) esto si se mostraba bien hasta que realice de nuevo una publicación en el servidor y fue cuando comenzó a mostrar ese error. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ayudaría si pones versión de tu framework .net, y alguna imagen de tu reporte para ver qué intentas realizar.

Comment: Adicionalmente revisa tu conexión de base datos (Connection string, etc)

Comment: ya lo corregí, el framework es 4.6.1 @jtaborga

Comment: Mi conexion esta bien, si puedo iniciar sesion a mi sitio y hacer todos tipo de acciones, el problema es ese error en los reportes, y no encuentro nada en la web @KodiakMx

Comment: ¿Están los mismos binarios de la antigua publicación? ¿En que navegador estás utilizando tu aplicación? Si usas la opción de F12 en el navegador, en modo consola y levantas tu aplicación, ¿te genera algún error? ¿Hubo cambio de framework?

Answer (score 0):

Yo me encontre con este error. Si buscas en ingles "Failed to load expression host assembly. Details: Could not load file or assembly", te saldra mas información. Pero basicamente el problema esta en una de las dll's que tienes en el servidor. Que en tu ordenador estan instalados y alli o no estan instalados, o tienen otras versiones.

A mi me pasaba con libreria "System.Web", que tenia versión diferente.

Otro tema que te puede pasar, es que no hay derechos de acceso por hacer una nueva pulicación. Es algo bastante tipico, que despues de publicaciones hay que reasignar los permisos, porque segun como, pueden borrarse. Si no hay permisos - tampoco es posible cargar librerias externas.

Aqui en stackoverflow hay una persona que ya tubo un problema muy similar y se dio con la solución: [respuesta encontrada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379804/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-in-reporting-services)